# Why are my string variables from my file getting printed over?

Tags: c++, string, file, getline

When I do my `getline` from the file and go to print that line it will get printed over if I try to print something on the same line as the variable. The last line of output is the only one that works correctly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

bool CheckIfPalindrome(string phrase);

int main() {
    ifstream inputFile;

    inputFile.open("p.txt");
    
    string line;
    bool isPalindrome;

    while(getline(inputFile, line)){
        isPalindrome = CheckIfPalindrome(line);
    
        if (isPalindrome == true) {
            cout << line << " is a palindrome" << endl;            
        } else {
            cout << line << " is not a palindrome" << endl;
        }
    }
    
    inputFile.close();
    return 0;
}

//Checks if the phrase is a palindrome
bool CheckIfPalindrome(string phrase) {
    bool isPalindrome = true;

    for (size_t i = 0 ; i <= phrase.length() ; i++) {
        if (phrase[i] != phrase[(phrase.length() - i) -1]){
            isPalindrome = false;
            i = 100;
        }
    }
    
    return isPalindrome;
}
```

The output is:

```
 is not a palindrome
 is not a palindrome
 is not a palindrome
 is not a palindrome Elba.
 is not a palindromeal: Panama!
 is not a palindrome
 is not a palindrome
racecar is a palindrome
```

so clearly it saves the string correctly, but just prints over the variable.
The complier is bash if that changes anything.

Comment: Tip: Pass in string arguments as `const std::string&` to avoid unnecessary copies and to avoid `using namespace std`.

Comment: PSA: Don't forget about [`begin()` and `end()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/begin) as well as the reverse counterparts. You can just straight up iterate here. This avoids hammering the `length()` function repeatedly.

Comment: Side note: [`bash`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)) is a [shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell) and an [interpreter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_(computing)), but not a [compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler). In particular, it is not a C++ compiler. However, you can use `bash` to run your C++ compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Use `break;` instead of  `i = 100;` to end the loop. Or just `return false;` immediately.

More importantly, the loop is going out of bounds of `phrase`, and is performing too many checks (you only need to iterate half of `phrase`).

Try this instead:

```
bool CheckIfPalindrome(const string &phrase) {

    size_t size = phrase.size();
    size_t halfway = size / 2;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < halfway; ++i) {
        if (phrase[i] != phrase[(size - i) - 1]){
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    return true;
}
```